# Is Solaris 11 Express a replacement for OpenSolaris?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

I was searching for OpenSolaris but landed in Oracle's website of Solaris 11 Express. Is OpenSolaris replaced by Solaris 11 Express?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct; Oracle is no longer contributing to OpenSolaris ([reference](http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/opensolaris-discuss/2010-August/059310.html)).  Oracle Solaris 11 Express releases more often than the standard build of Solaris and includes newer technologies.  It may be used free of charge for development and testing, but not for production.  Production use requires purchasing some form of Oracle Premier Support ([reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/overview/faqs-oraclesolaris11express-185609.pdf)).

[OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/) is an open-source continuation of the OpenSolaris project by the Illumos Foundation.

Comment: Is it free to use? When anything is acquired by Oracle, it is no longer available as FREE.

Comment: I think you have to pay for support and/or the access to updates. I'm in process of finding out. According to the "Oracle Technology Network Developer License Terms" No Technical Support: Our technical support organization will not provide technical support, phone support, or updates to you for the Programs licensed under this agreement.

Comment: @Rohit As mentioned above, it's free for testing/development.  You have to pay to use it for production or to obtain support/patches.

Comment: How successful and active is OpenIndiana? Does Solaris Express also comes bundled with applications like Linux flavors?

Comment: "Oracle Solaris 11 Express releases more often than the standard build of Solaris", actually, Oracle Solaris 11 Express *is* the latest release of the standard build of Solaris. Oracle is also still regularly contributing to various consolidations of the OpenSolaris source code repository ( http://serverfault.com/questions/216535/opensolaris-um-is-it-becoming-unmaintained/216560#216560 )